# RSA в Delphi (CryptoAPI)

Tags: delphi, криптография, rsa, шифрование

Здравствуйте, никак не получается совладать с *RSA* в *Delphi*.

Задача: имеется ключевая пара в формате *CryptoAPI*, необходимо этой ключевой парой шифровать-дешифровать строки. Перепробовал все методы из google'а, они либо расшифровывают билиберду, либо не шифруют вообще.

Ключи были сгенерированы [этой](http://pastebin.com/SHxTXwZM) программой. Она отлично шифрует-расшифровывает, но попытка портировать её код на дельфи провалилась.

**UPD**: Шифрую примером из [этой](http://seofork.ru/rsa-delphi-cryptoapi-php-openssl/) статьи. Еще неплохо бы расшифровку. Попробовал по образцу - не прокатило

**UPD2**: Засим вопрос закрывается, рабочий вариант, если кому понадобится - ниже.

```
function RSAEncrypt(source: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  KeyStream   : TResourceStream;
  Stream      : TMemoryStream;
  Base64      : TStringStream;
  RSA         : HCRYPTPROV;
  PublicKey   : HCRYPTKEY;
  strlen      : DWORD;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  KeyStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'PUBKEY', RT_RCDATA);
  CryptAcquireContext(@RSA, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
  CryptImportKey(RSA, PByte(KeyStream.Memory), KeyStream.Size, 0, 0, @PublicKey);
  strlen := Length(source);
  CryptEncrypt(PublicKey, 0, true, 0, nil, @strlen, 0);
  Stream.SetSize(strlen);
  strlen := Length(source);
  CopyMemory(Stream.Memory, pointer(source), strlen);
  CryptEncrypt(PublicKey, 0, true, 0, PByte(Stream.Memory), @strlen, Stream.Size);
  Base64 := TStringStream.Create;
  EncodeStream(Stream, Base64);
  Result := Base64.DataString;
  Base64.Free;
  Stream.Free;
  KeyStream.Free;
  CryptDestroyKey(PublicKey);
  CryptReleaseContext(RSA, 0);
end;

function RSADecrypt(source: AnsiString): AnsiString;
var
  Base64        : TStringStream;
  Stream        : TMemoryStream;
  KeyStream     : TResourceStream;
  RSA           : HCRYPTPROV;
  PublicKey     : HCRYPTKEY;
  strlen        : DWORD;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  KeyStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'PRIVKEY', RT_RCDATA);
  CryptAcquireContext(@RSA, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
  CryptImportKey(RSA, PByte(KeyStream.Memory), KeyStream.Size, 0, 0, @PublicKey);
  Base64 := TStringStream.Create(source);
  DecodeStream(Base64, Stream);
  Base64.Clear;
  strlen := Stream.Size;
  CryptDecrypt(PublicKey, 0, true, 0, PByte(Stream.Memory), @strlen);
  Stream.SetSize(strlen);
  Base64.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  Result := Base64.DataString;
  Base64.Free;
  Stream.Free;
  KeyStream.Free;
  CryptDestroyKey(PublicKey);
  CryptReleaseContext(RSA, 0);
end;
```

Comment: Вы ждёте слов сочувствия? Я Вам искренне сочувствую.

А если есть какой-то вопрос, так задайте его.

Comment: Есть какой-то вопрос. Например, такой: есть ли какой-нибудь рабочий пример?

Comment: Рабочий пример на delphi? Я про такой не слышал. Но. Немного уточним: шифруете примером из статьи. Ваша программа не расшифровывает. А какая-нибудь (не на delphi писаная) расшифровывает?

(да, просто для сведения. У меня ни delphi, ни виндов не установлено)

Comment: Сейчас у меня первое подозрение - на очень прямую обработку строк дельфей. Пробовал писать в файл вместо возвращаемого значения функции - расшифровывает. Еще есть подозрение на ключевую пару - я её читал не из ресурсов, а файлом.

Comment: Пример рабочего приложения в файле. 
<a href='http://fk-uran.com.ua/delphi-crypto-api-shifrovanie-potoka-dannyx-i-stroki-parolem/'>тут</a>

Comment: Сами ответьте на свой вопрос внизу, stackoverflow вам ещё рейтинг за это поднимет, вместо того что бы писать ответ в вопросе. P.S. спасибо